# Prove $f$ is riemann integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f(x)= \begin{cases} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{x} \right) &\text{ if } 0 < x < 1\\ 0 &\text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

I know a function is considered Riemann integrable if it is continuous and bounded. In this case, f is continuous on the interval $[-1, 1]$ and is also bounded. I'm inclined to believe this answer would satisfy the question. Is this enough or is there more I could prove?

This is page $82$ question $3.27$ of Advanced Calculus: An Introduction to Linear Analysis by Leonard Richardson.

Comment: notice $\sin(0) = 0,$ so $f$ is _really_ not piecewise defined. I guess you want $f(1) = 0$ too.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\sin (x/\pi)$? Because if so, there doesn't seem much point to specifying $0$ at $x=0$ since $\sin(0/\pi) = 0$ anyway.

Comment: @Jennifer You made a mistake in your edit. Its $\sin(\pi/x)$.

Comment: @ErinA If  you already have the result that $f$ continuous on $(0,1)$ and bounded on $[0,1]$ implies  $f$ integrable on $[0,1]$ then all you need to do is state $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. 

However, I suspect that you're meant to use $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ implies integrable on $[0,1]$ -- which means proving $f$ is continous at $0$, else the question seems too easy.

Comment: This question makes _less_ sense now than originally stated. what are the values in $[-1,0)$?

Comment: OP forgot to say that there is a hint: "You may use Exercise 3.26." Exercise 3.26 says that if a funciton is continuous on $(a,b)$ and bounded on $[a,b]$ then it is Riemann integrable. That exercise also has a hint to look at Theorem 3.2.4, which in turn says that if $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and if to every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P_0$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P_0)-L(f,P_0)<\epsilon$ then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. OP could have given all this information, of course...

Comment: @ZainPatel I wrote the question as it was stated in the book. My answer just seems too easy. I'm wondering if I've missed something or if I can further expand the proof.